# Target a certain PHP function with $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hey guys I have a scenario,

I want to use the ajax $.get method to target a certain PHP function in a separate PHP file. I am not too sure about the syntax.

The Javascript

```
function all(){

    $.get({
    url: "functions.php  THEN GET A CERTAIN FUNCTION  ",
    success:  function success(data){   paint(data) },
    dataType: "html"
    });


});
```

function.php

```
 <?php

function helloWorld(){

echo "Hello World";

};

    function helloMars(){

echo "Hello Mars";

};
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: What you need to do is indicate in some way that you want to trigger a certain function. Likely in the query. Then use some logic: `if/else` or a `switch` and detect if your trigger was set.  If it was, call your function.

Comment: url: "functions.php?fname=helloWorld",

Answer (score 1):

Pass a variable in the `data` attribute or URL query string, and in your PHP script, choose a function based on that variable.

```
$.get({
   url: "functions.php",
   data: { "vname": "something" },
   success:  function success(data){   paint(data) },
   dataType: "html"
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

PHP:

```
if ($_GET["vname"] == "something") {
   helloWorld();
} else {
   helloMars();
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: You don't have to use an if/else if the vname is the name of the function. $vname=$_GET['vname']; $vname();

Comment: That looks like a potential security hole to me. Someone could execute a function you didn't want executed if they guess the right name.

Comment: Since we don't know if this is working with direct user input we can't say for sure. And I think it's worth it to note functions can be called with variables. Also in your code, if the person "guessing" just guesses anything helloMars will always execute. That's not ideal I assume.

Comment: But at least they can't execute anything *except* `helloWorld` and `helloMars`. Your approach contains no sanitization whatsoever, and that's always a bad thing. Never, ever give unknown users the power to run code you didn't expect them to run.

Comment: @FunkDoc "Since we don't know if this is working with direct user input we can't say for sure" It doesn't matter since it's an ajax request done by the browser, so the user can always call this url by just looking into the source code. With some fantasy and testing they could execute functions you didn't want executed.

Comment: This is the correct approach, but I think most of us use "action" for the var name so it's consistent with standard get/post

Answer (score 0):

May this help you

```
$.get("test-ajax.php",function(data,status){

  $(".content").html(data);

});
```

"test-ajax.php" file

`function helloWorld()`

{
`echo "hello world";`
}

`function helloMars()`
{

`echo "Hello Mars";`

}

`helloWorld();`
`helloMars();`